# How to solve this problem by Lagrange duality?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multipliers

This is a convex problem and although it can be well solved by CVX, I want to know how it can be solved by the Lagrange duality method. The derivations with regard to $L_k$ and $B_k$ are constants, which means the closed-form solution cannot be presented. I'm confused and I need some insights that help me understand the problem deeply.
I will give my honest appreciation to these who clear up the doubts for me.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE! Please take a look at our [help](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site) here and try to write your problem using MathJax.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that this has a closed form solution.

Comment: I agree with @ErlingMOSEK (unsurprisingly). If you want to get a closed-form solution you need to get rid of the log. My suggestion would be to write out the KKT conditions and try something there, but it's going to be really tough. If you manage, please do share that here :)

Comment: Even if you replace the log by a linear function it will be hard. Because then you have an LP. That is my argument.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to solve this by :Lagrange Duality? What are you trying to accomplish which can't be done by numerical optimization, such as with CVX? See the "Edit" portion of my answer https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/can-we-get-the-closed-form-solution-for-this-problem/4787#4787 for reference on how CVXPY can be used to insert (the solution to) this optimization problem as a differentiable modeling layer in PyTorch  or TensorFlow models.

Comment: @ Mark L. Stone @ ErlingMOSEK @ Richard   I try to solve it by Lagrange duality combined with the subgradient method in a iterative way, whereas  my  algorithm cannot converge. I don't kown where goes wrong and I'm  eager for some explicit deducing process to show how to correctly solve this problem.

Comment: if you want an assessment of your algorithm, you should edit your question to provide a detailed exposition of your algorithm. Do you believe that your algorithm will do better than calling Mosek from CVX  or from using Mosek's Fusion?  if so, maybe @ErlingMOSEK will hire you. A re your problems to big for Mosek's 2nd order methofd?

Comment: The objective function seems to say $\max L_k$, which makes no sense since $k$ is a running index over $1,\dots,K$.